# jquery nextuntil filtering for multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to sort my site out so that when I click an anchor link it highlights the heading and the paras underneath it. I have it nearly right but am struggling with a few issues.

I have some HTML like:

```
<p id="pp1" class="Subsubhead">Stuff</p>
<p>Nonsense</p>
<p>More</p>
<p id="pp7" class="Subsubhead">Meow</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p class="subhead">
```

and I have some javascript that nearly works like:

```
function highlight(elemId) {
    var elem = $(elemId);

    elem.nextUntil(".Subsubhead").addClass("snaphighlight");

    //elem.addClass("snaphighlight");
    setTimeout(function () {
        elem.removeClass("snaphighlight")
    }, 1000);
}

$('#navigation a').click(function (event) {
    var elemId = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    highlight(elemId);
});
```

This currently doesn't highlight the heading, but it does highlight the `<p>` tags underneath it until the next Subsubhead.  however, when the next p has a class of Subhead, it keeps highlighting which I don't want either.  Is there a way of telling it to nextUntil `".subsubhead"&&".subhead"` or something similar? also my timeout doesn't work anymore. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the class to numerous elements but only removing it from one

Try this:

```
function highlight(elemId) {
    var elem = $(elemId);
    var highlight=elem.nextUntil(".Subsubhead").addClass("snaphighlight");

    //elem.addClass("snaphighlight");
    setTimeout(function () {
        highlight.removeClass("snaphighlight")
    }, 1000);
}
```

Your syntax using `##` for a jQuery selector is invalid, should only use one `#`

Comment: This works for the timeout. Using coldfusion so using one # causes issues. thats the only reason theres two. CF devs understand.

Comment: I do CF work also but posting a mix of server code and client code only adds confusion when all you have shown is html and javascript